# Does using inline assembly in modern C++ have some benefits now?

Tags: c++, optimization, inline-assembly

I'm interesting will I have any benefits now if I use inline assemble in modern C++ with modern compilers like GCC 4.7 and VS12? E.g. for vectorization and some small optimisations? Or it is just naughtiness and with modern optimising compilers using it in any scope gives me nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of inline assembly makes your code architecture specific. Even for things like `vectorization`, you now rely on the fact that the target which executes this code needs to support these special/enhanced instruction sets.

And let's say if someone tries to port your code from `x86` to `ARM`, they would have a tough time with it.

I'd suggest to have a mechanism by which you could detect if the target supports vector instruction sets like SSE2 or SSE3 and execute your optimized code and have a failsafe code in place which runs on targets which don't support the enhanced instruction sets.

Linux kernel for example abstracts all architecture specific code under the `arch` directory and there are implementations of the same function for different architectures. If you know that your code might get executed on multiple different architectures, you could do something similar by coming up with your own abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

As with many things, it depends.

For most code that you're likely to write, inline assembly is not likely to be helpful. Modern compilers are reasonably smart, and will usually generate code that is at least as good as anything you could write. (And they'll generate it quite a bit faster than you could write and debug it, too.)

The exception is, as you've guessed, in writing certain vector code. While some compilers will attempt to vectorize certain loops, they don't do as good of a job as a skilled human can. In certain applications (e.g, DSP, video encoding, etc.) this can make a significant difference. However, this requires detailed knowledge of the processor you're coding for -- badly written vector code will often perform even worse than the scalar code the compiler would come up with!

Bottom line: Unless you have very good reason to believe you **need** to write inline assembly, avoid it.

Comment: Also, many compilers now provide intrinsic functions, to access these vector instructions without giving up the type safety of C++, while retaining a similar degree of control as inline assembly provides.  In essence, with intrinsics, you choose the instructions to use, but the compiler performs register allocation.

Comment: @BenVoigt: There's that too. Compilers tend to generate questionable to outright bad code for intrinsics, though.

Comment: @duskwuff How that? Looking at the MS provided intrinsics most of them map to one or two actual assembly instructions. And the obvious problem with inline asm is that it may cause the compiler to be extremely careful with optimizations itself (gcc has its horribly complex syntax to avoid that though).

Comment: @Voo: While generating code for the intrinsics *themselves* is obvious enough, generating the code around them isn't. When they aren't just generating faulty code entirely, compilers will often end up doing really stupid things like spilling vectors to the stack.

Comment: As to inline assembly, the metadata provided for gcc inlines is insufficient. The compiler still has to be super-paranoid about any memory the inline asm may have modified.

Answer (score 1):

Generally what you're looking for are intrinsic functions that thinly wrap specific instructions.

This lets you access e.g. vector instructions without giving up the type safety of C++, while retaining a similar degree of control as inline assembly provides. In essence, with intrinsics, you choose the instructions to use, but the compiler performs register allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is a little bit like the English expression "how long is a piece of string" - it can't be easily answered without actually unwinding the whole piece of string. Same here, without knowing what the code actually is supposed to do, it's hard to say if there is a benefit or not.

My general approach is to write the code using C or C++, and then see what the compiler does. If it's fast enough [whatever that is defined as], then there's no need to do anything else. If there is a lack of speed, then look at the code, see if there's any trivial algorithmic optimisation, or simplification, splitting functions to avoid an if-statement in the middle of the code, etc, etc. Profile the code, see where it's spending its time.

After each step of improvement [measure, and keep track of the changes, settings, etc - I usually have spreadsheet with data of "with this change, it runs 4% faster", "with this, it ran 2% slower"].

Once you have exhausted all other options, then you can start thinking about inline assembler. And sometimes, if you "do the right thing", there can be big improvements. At other times, there's not much to be gained at all.

I wrote some memory benchmarks recently, using `gcc`. When I used `volatile` (to force the memory writes to actually happen), the compiler produced pretty rubbish code, so when I wrote the corresponding code in inline assembler, it was 3-4 times faster. However, once I rearranged the code to actually use the written to memory in a step after the memory write itself, and removed the `volatile`, the compiler was just as good as my SSE2 code.

For complex SSE code, I still think the compiler lacks a little bit in some cases, but it can be pretty clever at times - it certainly optimizes simple loops to full SSE2 code.

The biggest gains I've found is when the compiler simply doesn't understand what you actually want to have happen [or it's not capable of generating the right code for the operations you want]. Non-temporal moves are one example of this - you don't want to store something in the cache, because you know it's not going to be useful in the cache anyway.